# ERP Implemented website to Android app

Tags: android, erp

I need to create an application for an ERP implemented website.
For example,
http://evarsity.srmuniv.ac.in/srmswi/usermanager/youLogin.jsp
is an ERP implemented website which displays the attendance and results of the students.
I dont need a webview or anyother similar type.
I need my own custom UI embedded with this ..
Can you help me?

Comment: it depends on how much you pay ... SO is not "looking for free programmer" service ... and pls check what ERP means